A100 Problem: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call
I have 4 A100 80G GPU. I always meet error when I use
device_map="auto"

The error is :
CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.

But when I set it to cpu or cuda:0. The error will be disappear .
Can anyone explain why?
Here is my code from Llama3 official one:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
import torch

model_id = "meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    device_map="auto",
)

messages = [
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a pirate chatbot who always responds in pirate speak!"},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Who are you?"},
]

input_ids = tokenizer.apply_chat_template(
    messages,
    add_generation_prompt=True,
    return_tensors="pt"
).to(model.device)

terminators = [
    tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids("<|eot_id|>")
]

outputs = model.generate(
    input_ids,
    max_new_tokens=256,
    eos_token_id=terminators,
    do_sample=True,
    temperature=0.6,
    top_p=0.9,
)
response = outputs[0][input_ids.shape[-1]:]
print(tokenizer.decode(response, skip_special_tokens=True))


I encountered the same Error several times.
In my first case, the issue was caused by the sizes mismatch between the tokenizer length and model input. I solved with:
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))

the mismatch was induced when adding pad token:
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '<pad>'})

In my second case, the raw labels of imagery segmentation dataset are messed with outlier/overrange label. The Error showed in the loss.backward() line.  I solved with ignore the overrange label:
criterion = CrossEntropyLoss2d(ignore_index=255).cuda() 

You may run the CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1 python filename.py args or add the os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = "1" to the file head to check the detailed error information. For example, my detailed error information is:
C:\cb\pytorch_1000000000000\work\aten\src\ATen\native\cuda\NLLLoss2d.cu:93: block: [1,0,0], thread: [183,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.

